# How to run junit tests of a program in daikon?

Tags: java, junit

When I type in `java daikon.DynComp org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` or `java daikon.Chicory org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` from the command line, I always get this as a result:

JUnit version 4.12

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Too many parameters for an annotation method
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:66)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.annotationType(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSelectAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:266)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotatedElement.java:258)
    at java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class.java:3425)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.wrapIfNotThreadSafe(RunNotifier.java:50)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.addFirstListener(RunNotifier.java:212)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:134)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
```

Moreover when I try to run other programs in daikon has running junit as part of the code, the same error always occurs. What should I do?

Comment: Please give a concrete, reproducible test case.  Show the full command line (including classpath) and provide all necessary files to reproduce the problem.

Comment: All I have is a junit-4.12.jar file in the directory, and daikon 5.6.4 fully installed (and daikon added to CLASSPATH). My full command line is "java -cp .:$CLASSPATH daikon.DynComp org.junit.runner.JUnitCore".

Comment: `.` on your path will not pick up the `junit-4.12.jar` file in that directory.  Did you make a mistake, or is `.` not necessary? 
 Also, please give the exact classpath.

Comment: @mernst Sorry, my full command is actually "java -cp .:$CLASSPATH:junit-4.12.jar daikon.DynComp org.junit.runner.JUnitCore", with junit-4.12.jar inside the current directory. My full $CLASSPATH is "/home/lvyiwei1/daikon-5.6.4/daikon.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar"

Comment: When I tried that, I got the error "Can't find dcomp_premain.jar on the classpath and $DAIKONDIR is not set." So you need to set DAIKONDIR or put that other file in the current directory.  (When I did that, I could finally reproduce your problem.) 
However, there is a more important problem: the base command (without Daikon) doesn't work. I tried to run `java -cp .:$CLASSPATH:junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` and got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing`. The base command needs to work before you try to add Daikon.  Please fix CLASSPATH or the `-cp` argument.

Comment: @mernst I included "hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" to the same directory and changed the classpath to "-cp .:$CLASSPATH:junit-4.12.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar". Now running the command without dyncomp works fine, but running dyncomp still creates the same assertion error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug in Daikon](https://github.com/codespecs/daikon/issues/129) that has been [fixed](https://github.com/codespecs/daikon/commit/639c429dea2bd39ef788aabdfe874deed89ca4b6).